# Very Slow Responses On Homestead

Tags: homestead, lumen-5.2

**Versions:**

- Lumen: 5.2
- Vagrant: 1.8.1
- Homestead: latest

I have just installed Homestead and am attempting to use it for developing a Lumen application. The Lumen app is very fast on MAMP (as expected), however is extremely slow on Homestead. While I expect a performance drop when using a VM, the performance drop I am experiencing is essentially rendering Homestead unusable.

I am on OS X Yosemite and have 16GB of RAM and 8 logical cores. I am also using VirtualBox to run my VM.

**Homestead.yaml**

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 4096
cpus: 2
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/repos
      to: /home/vagrant/Code
      type: nfs

sites:
    - map: my-site.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/my-site/public

databases:
    - homestead
```

Inside my nginx config:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index /index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    }
```

While running my test suite via PHPUnit is lightning fast (running from both within Homestead and from my local file system), responses in the browser are painfully slow. For example, a simple route returning `hello world` takes 5 - 10 seconds to respond.

What can I do to increase the response time? Are there any other settings that I can optimize?

Answer (score 1):

In my case in windows is because virtualbox uses VBOXSF as a file system to mount folders from host to guest, I don't know why but it is slow.

If you mount the folder using CIFS it should runs a lot faster.

on the guest side you should do this  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently

I don't use mac so I'm not sure how to do it on the HOST side, but I guess that you only need to Share the folder to the network using SMB.

good luck.